# Embed jquery.corner.js in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, embed

i would like to embed jquery.corner.js in my wordpress theme, but i had no luck...

What is the proper way to embed this script in a wordpress theme and use it?

This is the script's url, just in case: http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). Add the file to your theme folder.

```
function include_jquery_corner(){
  wp_register_script( 'jq_corner', get_template_directory_uri() . 'PATH TO YOUR JS FILE' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jq_corner' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'include_jquery_corner' );
```